# Workflow library InfoPath forms process does not start MS SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Headache InfoPath continues, the workflow does not start, when you save the form in the library , no mistakes is not writing at all ... in the Workflow configuration is run , while maintaining and changing element . Who solved the problem? Tired of manually run ...

With workflow lists never any problem does not happen ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood, a problem with conversion in PDF... the recommended product property for worker process - http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/02/tuning-sharepoints-workflow-engine.html